# Swift 3 getURL Ambiguous Data

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift 3 I am getting an error on th is line of code:

```
let task = getURLSession().dataTask(with: request ) {
        (data, response, error) in
```

The error is "Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'
I'm not sure how to fix it.  It worked fine in 2.3.

Comment: Can you show us a minimized code to reproduce your issue? That two line cannot generate "Ambiguous reference ...", if I fill out other parts with my guess.

Comment: Frequently these sorts of errors arise if there are other problems, e.g. `getURLSession()` isn't returning what you think it should, or if `request` isn't of the type you think it is. Or sometimes it can be a result of some completely unrelated error on some preceding line.

Comment: You are probably passing a NSMutableRequest when you should be passing a URLRequest. To make it "mutable" just declare it using `var request = URLRequest()`